# asp.net mvc3 - how to set Devpath?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, gac

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cskzh7h6.aspx

gives information about turning on devpath, but how to you set this variable? Unfortunately it's not very clear on how you can set it. Is it set for all referenced dlls once set? Or can you set per dll?

I have also read that http://www.reflector.net/ offers a tool for GAC management. Most information I found on Devpath is linked with this tool.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

DEVPATH is a Windows environment variable so use the SET command or set it up in Control Panel

Comment: if I just set devpath. I still can't compile my solution. Is devpath for deployment only?